# Serialization problem

Tags: c#, serialization

The situation is like this : Main project A. and a class library B. **A references B**

Project B has the classes that will be serialized. The classes are used in A. Now, the problem appears when from Project A I try to serialize the objects from B. An exception is thrown that says a class from A cannot be serialized. This is the strange part since in the classes in B I cant have a reference to those in A. (a circular dependency would be created).

How can I track down the problem ? because the exception method doesn't say where the Problem appeared ?

**Edit :** 
Ok, I found the problem with the help of **Kent Boogaart's** small app :D . I have a PropertyChanged listener in a class in project A that is not marked Serializable - and I don't want to mark it so. ( it would serialize that class to right ?)

I've solved the problem with the event by following this link : [.NET 2.0 solution to serialization of objects that raise events](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CommentView,guid,776f44e8-aaec-4845-b649-e0d840e6de2c.aspx#commentstart).
There still is a problem , but it's probably something similar.

**PS:** Great tool from **Kent Boogaart**

Comment: Are you doing something with a WebService in Project A?

Comment: Please post the exception message.

Comment: Exactly what are you doing (binary serialization, xml serialization, datacontract serialization, ....)?  And what is the exception you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have written a tool called [sertool](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/sertool) that will tell you what in your object graph cannot be serialized and how it is being referenced.

Comment: This tool is super useful, thanks! It is worth noting that when I went to the blog, I had to independently sign in to Windows Live for the download to be available (without sign in, there was just a white square...).

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to isolate the problem to a specific class. Then you can implement custom serialization and debug it to find the real problem.

Just a simple implementation to let you step through the process:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[Serializable]
public class Test : ISerializable
{
    private Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Test));

        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor property = properties.Find(entry.Name, false);
            property.SetValue(this, entry.Value);
        }
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Test));

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
        {
            info.AddValue(property.Name, property.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Kent's tool also looks very nice and will, without doubt, help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your objects from B are storing references to objects from A using classes/interfaces that are not part of A or B, For example, if B is storing objects from A using an object (System.Object) reference

Answer (score 0):

Let's say TA and TB are types defined in A and B. Let's say there's an interface I either in B or an assembly both B and A reference. TA implements I. TB has a public, settable property of type I named P.

You can now do this:

```
TB b = new TB();
b.P = new TA();
```

Since TA implements I, this is possible.

Now your object graph has an instance of a type that may not be serializable and comes from assembly A.