# How to identify where a c__DisplayClass is not marked as Serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to mark a (quite complex) class as `[Serializable]` which involves finding all the types used and making them as `[Serializable]`. I have come across one now where the exception is:

```
Type kAI.Core.kAIXmlBehaviour+<>c__DisplayClass24 is not marked as Serializable.
```

Where should I start looking? I have been trying to identify elements that when I don't serialise don't cause it, but the branching factor is massive and I've no idea what this DisplayClass24 means or why it is a sub class of XmlBehaviour. I read somewhere that it is a lambda expression. Does that mean I am trying to store a lambda expression, or that the type was created in a lambda expression?

Comment: That's probably from an event handler.

Comment: I feared that, but when I attempt to make an event handler as shouldn't be serialized, it tells me: `Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.`

Comment: Use `[field: NonSerialized]` http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/about-net-events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a number of things. Firstly, I was using an anonymous getter/setter:

```
public kAIINodeObject NodeContents
{
   get;
   private set;
}
```

Which I couldn't mark as `[NonSerialized]` on account of being a property. This can be resolved by simply making the object.

SLaks correctly noted that event handlers were being serialised, events can be marked using

```
[field: NonSerialized]
```

Finally, [this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182091/958004) is very useful for tracking down where the objects are.